# Visual Studio 2012 Error 0xC0000005 Array output

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2012, memory

I'll try to keep this as short and simple as I can.
I have a decent sized text based RPG in the works as a project for my class. When I try to generate the list of weapons available, I get the error:

Unhandled exception at 0x613240F6 (msvcp110.dll) in game.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFD9EC31

I found a lot about this error but was unable to find a relevant post that helped with my problem. Everything I found had to do with pointers, which I am not using (which I should be, I just don't really understand them and wrote most of this running on 2 hours of sleep and 3 shots of espresso...)

The code is kind of cumbersome and long so I posted the 3 relevant things, the function in which I am getting the error, the function that generates the weapons, and the weapon class.

The code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/Z1D98rke)

Thanks so much for any help you guys can offer!

Comment: Your first problem was using C++ to write a text based RPG.

Comment: First of all that was absolutely irrelevant and second of all like I said, it's for a class, I was told to write a text based game in C++ using object oriented principals. So I was a bit limited.

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but the `weaponGen` function has a huge amount of redundant code. You only need one `Weapon` local variable, the whole function could be reduced to 3 lines .  And `randStats` should operate on its argument by reference, rather than returning by value.

Comment: Matt McNabb - Thanks man. Like I said, running on no sleep I wrote this. I went back through and cleaned up the weaponGen function very well. However, I am a bit confused as to what you mean with my randStats function.

Comment: Can we get the code here please? The pastebin link is dead. Dont use pastebin for code in SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I examined your code and found an issue with the way you are indexing the `shopSelection` array. You are indexing a 7th element that does not exist and this explains the access violation error that is being reported. Since the array has a size of 6 then the maximum index is 5.

Comment: This is exactly the issue, and I very literally wish I could smack myself in the face for having asked this question in the first place. I've been coding for quite a few years now (though C++ is a new and very hard language for me to understand) and I am very aware that indexes of arrays start at zero and always end at max size - 1. Like I said, running on 2 hours of sleep and 3 shots of espresso, I pounded out ~ 600 lines of code and never realized how sloppy my arrays were. Thanks so much

Comment: @MichaelWard - Always remember that a fresh pair of eyes will see with much greater clarity.